# Redux forms, is there a good way to make a checkbox list with toggle all functionality?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using last redux-form v6.5.0.
I'm wondering what is the best solution to make a toggle all component using what the library has.

I ended up adding different fields in my form and playing redux form action creators and with react life cycles, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Are there any examples out there?

What I've done so far is having in the render a structure like this:

```
...

<Field
    name='toggleAll'
    component={Ckbox}
    onChange={this.toggleAllProfile} />
<div>
{
    SUB_FIELDS.map((field, i) => (
        <Field key={i} name={field} component={Ckbox} />
    ))
}
</div>
```

the subfields is an array of names, something like this:

```
const SUB_FIELDS = ['field1', field2, field3, ...];
```

then I have a componentWillReceiveProps where I check if the subfields are checked or not toggling the toggleAll checkbox accordingly.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const {
    profiles,
  } = nextProps;
  const allFieldsChecked = SUB_FIELDS.filter(
    el => nextProps[el]
  ).length === SUB_FIELDS.length;

  if (
    allFieldsChecked &&
    toggleAll
  ) {
    return;
  } else if (
    allFieldsChecked &&
    !toggleAll
  ) {
    this.props.change('toggleAll', true);
  } else if (
    !allFieldsChecked &&
    profiles
  ) {
    this.props.change('toggleAll', false);
  }
}
```

and a method to toggle them all on the toggleAll onChange

```
toggleAllProfile = (e) => {
  SUB_FIELDS.forEach(field => {
    this.props.change(field, e.target.checked);
  });
};
```

This is working fine, but those fields aren't the only one in my form component and it can get really messy adding more fields with different needs.

I've tried using the `Fields` component but then it looked like too many renders.

I thought to make them in a separate component but then I will need to wrap this component in another form, so I'll end up having 2 `redux-form`s am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought to make them in a separate component but then I will need to
>   wrap this component in another form, so I'll end up having 2
>   redux-forms am I wrong?

Fortunately, yes, you are wrong! You only need to decorate a top level component with `reduxForm()`. That component can render child components which can also use `<Field />` or other `redux-form` components. You *may* want to decorate those child components using other selectors from `redux-form` to inject relevant form state, but you should not have to decorate it with `reduxForm()`.

> I've tried using the Fields component but then it looked like too many
>   renders.

It should only re-render when it is checked/unchecked or when one of your subfields is checked/unchecked. If it's in a separate component that just renders a single checkbox, that shouldn't be a huge performance issue. If you're seeing more re-renders than that, it's worth investigating why. Finding the cause can teach you important lessons on how to prevent performance issues in the future.

What you have now works okay and looks okay. Using `<Fields />` is probably the recommended way.

**Edit**

To clarify, if you make a separate component, it *should* just render your toggle-all checkbox; you should render your subfields separately from this. This will prevent subfields 1-n from re-rendering when you've only checked subfield 0.

Comment: Thanks I'll try something out, I was pretty sure that I had to decorate the child component but I could have been wrong (hopefully)!

Comment: If it helps you can review these http://sslotsky.react-violet-forms.surge.sh/ In particular, the 3rd example demonstrates using the `<Fields />` component to read from multiple checkbox inputs. It also renders those checkboxes, which I said not to do, but in my case it worked out fine.

Comment: I ended up extracting my fields in an external component as you suggested and it worked smoothly, I don't know why it didn't back there. For now I kept different `<Field />` instead of using the `<Fields />` but just because I already spent too much time on it. If I'll look into it I'll get back to you about that. Thank you for now!